# imports in python

Tags: python, импорт

Возникла следующая проблема. Есть следующая структура, к примеру:

```
bots/
    configs/
           __init__.py
           token.py
    temp/
           __init__.py
           bot.py
```

token.py:

```
BotToken = "sssssssss"
```

bot.py:

```
import telebot
from bots.configs.config import BotToken

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BotToken)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello')
```

Получаю ошибку при запуске bot.py:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bots'
```

Не понимаю в чём проблема, в документации написано

```
Users of the package can import individual modules from the package, for example:

import sound.effects.echo
```

При такой же структуре.

Comment: ну так у вас файл не `config` , а `token` . `from bots.configs.tokenimport BotToken`

Comment: Чтобы модуль знал, что он часть пакета, запускать надо так (как модуль пакета): `python -m bots.temp.bot`. Вы  скорее всего запускаете отдельно файл bot.py (двойным щелчком или `python bot.py`), из-за этого Python не понимает, что bot.py является частью какого-то пакета.